# How to redirect the output of findstr to a file?

Tags: batch-file, redirect, findstr

I have a batch file that i wish to take the output of the `findstr` command and redirect it to a file.

```
Type "%CH% log.txt" | Findstr /v "%lastMod%" > "%CH% log.txt"
```

The variables **CH** and **lastMod** are already defined, and whenever I remove the redirect operator it outputs to the screen exactly what i want it to output.`Type "%CH% log.txt" | Findstr /v "%lastMod%"` Whenever I add the redirect operator, it outputs nothing to my file (the file is empty). I have tried to find answers by useing keywords like findstr, redirect, to file, and undocumented `findstr`, with no luck. I was wondering if anyone knows the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output file is the same as your input file. Since you are not using append mode, it  effectively clears the file contents before the TYPE command has a chance to type out the original contents. Your FINDSTR never sees any input!

The solution is to redirect to a new temporary file, and then move the temp file to the original name when done.

```
type "%CH% log.txt" | findstr /v "%lastMod%" > "%CH% log.txt.new"
move /y "%CH% log.txt.new" "%CH% log.txt" >nul
```

You could simplify a bit by letting FINDSTR read the file directly

```
findstr /v "%lastMod%" "%CH% log.txt" > "%CH% log.txt.new"
move /y "%CH% log.txt.new" "%CH% log.txt" >nul
```